# Count all the value in two table via un function SQL and pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here's what I've done so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_JOB_COUNT (p_empid in employees.employee_id%type, e_empid in job_history.employee_id%type)

return number
is 
Job_numb number;
begin  
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ob_history)) 
into job_numb
FROM  dual
where employee_id = p_empid and employee_id = e_empid;
return number;
end;
```

the function is supposed to calculate the number of job the employee I've been working on since the beginning of his career, I use HR and it's an exercise to get ready for the exam but I cannot figure how to do it please help a beginner

Comment: You must to give an alias to the tables, because oracle can’t distinguish between which employee id corresponds at each other.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to calculate each number separately and then sum them up.

```
create or replace function get_job_count
  (p_empid in employees.employee_id%type)
return number
is
  l_cnt_emp  number;
  l_cnt_hist number;
  job_numb   number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt_emp
    from employees
    where employee_id = p_empid;
  
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt_hist
    from ob_history
    where employee_id = p_empid;
    
  job_numb := l_cnt_emp + l_cnt_hist;
  return job_numb;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> the function is supposed to calculate the number of job the employee [has] been working on since the beginning of his career

From my reading of the question, the only thing you need to check that the employee exists and, if they do, count is the number of rows in the `job_history` table and then add 1 as the employee's current job will not be in the history table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_JOB_COUNT (
  p_empid in employees.employee_id%type
) return number
IS
  Job_numb number;
BEGIN
  SELECT 0
  INTO   job_numb
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

  SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
  INTO   job_numb
  FROM   job_history
  WHERE  employee_id = p_emp_id;

  RETURN job_numb;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code the only change you should do is to move the condition from the dual table, which it's wrong in many levels.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_JOB_COUNT (p_empid in employees.employee_id%type, e_empid in job_history.employee_id%type)

return number
is 
Job_numb number;
begin  
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees where employee_id = p_empid) + 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ob_history where employee_id = e_empid)) as total
into job_numb
FROM  dual;
return number;
end;
```